# typeError: Cannot destructure property 'init' of 'object null' as it is null in ngx e-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, echarts

I got this when I was using ngx-echarts. When using versions 4.x.x everything worked fine. After an npm i the application failed to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proposed by @Arokia Lijas didn't work for me It generated errors in build --prod

so I found this one :

```
export function chartModule(): any {
      return import('echarts');
        }
```

and in NgModule:

```
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
  echarts: chartModule
}),
```

It did work perfectly for me.
Source: https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/issues/241#issuecomment-742777787

Comment: Bro I was pulling my hair out, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The problem was because of a version update in ngxe-charts. If using versions >5.0 use this in app.module

```
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
       echarts: { init: echarts.init }
  })
```

In tsconfig.json in angular compiler options add this too

```
"enableIvy": false
```